# Doxygen cannot open dot and map graphviz files

Tags: eclipse, doxygen, graphviz

I've been using Doxygen with the Eclipse Eclox plugin for some time now, with the automatic class dot diagrams working fine.

Recently I tried adding a dot graph of my own, using the `\dot` command. This worked, so I added another. Now neither of the new dot graphs get made.

Doxygen says:

> Error: Could not open image
>   `C:/Users/Me/git/Project/Documentation/html/dot_inline_dotgraph_1.png'
>   generated by dot! Error: problems opening map file
>   C:/Users/Me/git/Project/Documentation/html/dot_inline_dotgraph_1.map
>   for inclusion in the docs! If you installed Graphviz/dot after a
>   previous failing run,  try deleting the output directory and rerun
>   doxygen.

I have tried setting `SHORT_NAMES` to yes, setting disabling Dot clean-up...
I have even tried deleting and re-cloning the entire project from Git... It runs fine without any of my own dot graphs but the error returns as soon as I add even one small dot graph.

I have assumed so far that the output folder mentioned is the doxygen folder where my HTML and LaTeX files are saved to after a doxygen run finished is that correct?

I see a lot of people had this problem from some time ago (GViz v 2.2) but have come across threads where devs from both doxy and graphviz have promised fixes yet I am on v2.30 GViz and Doxygen v1.8.4 but have not been able to find a solid fix for this that actually works... anybody had any luck with other fixes for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah Here! There was a space in the graph names so they weren't getting made!!! Talk about a misleading error message!

Comment: Can you still reproduce this problem with the current version (1.8.13) of doxygen, if so can you provide a small example?

Comment: Interestingly this exact error message also appears if you provide empty graphs, by, for example starting the graph with `\dot`and then just ending it without any content with `\enddot`.